# How do I force a cookie to expire in Express.js?

Tags: express, passport.js

I'm using *Express.js* with *Passport.js*.

When the user doesn't check 'Remember me', I want any cookies to expire immediately.

I know that Passport.js is working because there is a valid `req.session.passport` object

But when I try to get the cookie to expire as follows:

```
req.session.cookie.expires = false;
```

There is an *error* because

```
req.session.cookie is undefined.
```

What am I doing wrong and/or how and when does `req.session.cookie` get yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logout()` method provided by passport.js

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Here is the passport.js [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/logout) describing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear cookie with `res.clearCookie(name [, options])`

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie

access cookie with `req.cookies`

set cookie with `res.cookie(name, value [, options])`